# Spring Boot JPA with Mysql getting error while update Entity

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently working on Spring boot with mysql. one of the DB column is NOT NULL, When create first time with all required field is successfully, but i'm trying to update some fields, this time getting error if not null column is not hold any value. How to avoid this colum while update, beacuse this column already having value in DB.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@DynamicUpdate(true)
public class User  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email; // email is not null column
    private String mobile;
}
```

All field having value in DB while update, so i'm just trying to update only name. My expectation is which field having value that filed only i want to update.

If email filed is having value while update, no issues, It's Successfully updated. I don't know where i have missed something.

```
@Override
public User update(User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

When i try to update following error is thrown

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'email' cannot be null
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3198) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3077) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3457) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:599) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1436) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:493) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3206) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2412) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy254.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Please add exception stack trace in  your question

Comment: I believe that, you could find my stack trace, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

> How to avoid this colum while update, beacuse this column already
>   having value.
>   My expectation is which field having value that filed only i want to update.

In your case you don't want update the null valued field but in other use cases, the field could be valued to null because we want to really update it to null.
The EntityManager cannot guess for you the fields to update or to not update.

You have two ways :

- retrieve the entity and set to it the new values, then save the entity with  `JpaRepository`/`CrudRepository` `save()`
- don't update the entity with JpaRepository/CrudRepository `save()` method but write your  JPQL update query where you specified fields (here `name`) to update and execute it with an `EntityManager`.

Comment: Thanks for your response David, I'm ok with you, if one field we can retrive and set, but in case of larege no. of filed need to set mean, how to proceed, It's not good way, correct.

Comment: The EntityManager cannot guess for you the fields to update or to not update. I understood, that's why i put Jacson annotation for exclude null value field.

Comment: You are welcome :) Please try to reduce your comment to a single one to make them readable. Jackson is not Hibernate. The field is indeed not serialized by Jackson but Hibernate still consider the NotNull annotation on your fields and JPA/Hibernate doesn't provide a way to dynamically ignore null fields during entity update. It is very really too specific.

Comment: I'm clear after reading your suggest, Can you tell any oher specific way is there? I want to update genereic way.Thanks.

Comment: If nullable column already having value, but while update not set any value mean not updated null value in DB, It's update only which filed having value.This time how it's possible EntityManager cannot guess for the fields to update or to not update?

Comment: Suppose that a client modifies the entity to really set the field to null, JPA will not ignore it silently and not change the value in the DB. Which could be misleading for the client. It will throw an exception to signal the not expected value. Keep things simple and without guess about the behavior makes the API clearer.

Comment: There is any possibilities way to update only not null field?, I want to update only which filed having value(NOT NULL and EMPTY)  Thanks